# cannot get sqlalchemy and pandas (to_sql) to write an dataframe index date into a MySQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I read from an API the following data into a pandas dataframe:

[image]

Now, I want to write this data into a MySQL-DB-table, using pandas to_sql:

[image]

In MySQL, the column is set up correctly, but has not written the values:

[image]
[image]

Then I looked in the debugger to show me the dataframe:

[image]

I thought it would maybe a formatting issue, and added the following lines:

[image]

In the debugger, it looks now fine:

[image]

But now, in the database, it wants to write the index column as text

[image]

... and interrupts the execution with an error:

[image]

Is there a way to get this going, aka to write df index data as date into a MySQL DB using pandas to_SQL in connection with a sqlalchemy engine?

Edit:
Table schema:

[image]

DataFrame Header:

[image]

Comment: can you provide sql table schema along with pandas dataframe head?

Comment: Hi, I just added the requested information to the bottom of my question

Comment: Use `VARCHAR` type with a limit for fields with primary key.

Comment: Hi. Thx for your answer. I was not really clear with my question: Can I get this going AND the index (~ date) column will be automatically correctly recognized and set up as DATE in MySQL?

Comment: No if are using `VARCHAR` date column won't be in datetime format. Refer to my answer.

Comment: Immediately after creating the DataFrame with the API data (and before you mess with it any more) run `df_info = priceData.info(verbose=True)` and [edit] your question to show the results. (Side note: Posting code, error messages, etc. as images is strongly discouraged. Paste that information into your question as text. See [ask] for details.)

Comment: Please, please avoid using screenshots for text/number data. See: [You should not post code as an image because...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `Date` column as primary key. I would suggest not to use that as primary key instead you should use `Date + Ticker` as primary key.